# Placing toolbars in Border layout

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am having difficulty placing a toolbar between two grids in a border layout.
The window has a grid at the top of the window, a toolbar beneath that window, and a second collapsible grid at the bottom.

When I docked it to the top panel, it either appeared at the bottom or top of the whole window. When I docked it to the top grid, it was cut off in the window unless you scrolled to it. When I set the toolbar to center, I have to scroll to it, and the entire grid stops rendering correctly.

Does anyone know any best practices for making a toolbar appear between two grids in a border layout?

```
Ext.define('MyProject.view.MyForm', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'dataInputForm',

layout:'border',
defaults: {
    collapsible: true,
    split: true,
    bodyStyle: 'padding:0px'
},
listeners: {
    show: function (grid, options) {
    }
},
requires: [
    'MyProject.view.MyGrid'
],
initComponent: function () {
  // some logic goes here for determining what buttons should be disabled,     
  // so toolbar buttons must be declared in initComponent.
   this.items = [
        {
            region:'north',
            collapsible: false,
            items: [
                new MyProject.view.MyGrid({
                    region: 'north',
                    showParentLineItemDescription: this.showParentLineItemDescription
                })]
        },
            {
        region:'center',
        collapsible:'false',
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        ui: 'footer',
        enableOverflow: true,
        items: [
            { xtype: 'tbspacer' },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'FirstButton',
                id: 'firstButton'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'tbspacer'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Second Button',
                id: 'secondButton'

            }
    },//end toolbar
    {
            title: 'Collapsible Grid',
                    xtype: 'collapsibleGrid',
                    region: 'south',                
                  collapsible: true
        }
]//end items
 this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

Edit:
Putting the toolbar as a dockedItem was the trick. Here was the transition from the first grid to the toolbar:

```
new MyProject.view.MyGrid({
                region: 'north',
                showParentLineItemDescription:      
       this.showParentLineItemDescription
            })
],
dockedItems : [
    collapsible:'true',
    xtype: 'toolbar',
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your code?

Comment: What is the toolbar related to? Top window or bottom window? If top, dock bottom to the top window. If bottom, dock top to the bottom window. If you want it standalone, attach it to an empty panel (like you are doing in your snippet except that it needs to attach to a panel.)

Comment: Thank you, Amol. That was the answer. I thought I had tried that before.